# Shivarahasya Purana original Sanskrit book free available online?

Tags: shiva, puranas

I have found an English version of Shivarahasya Purana on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/ShriShivaRahasya). But unable to find the original Sanskrit version.  Kindly share if anyone know of the original Sanskrit book other than scanned manuscripts.